# .htaccess to redirect to new domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to redirect my existing domain to new one (bot sites structure are same) I tried following in .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

My problem is, If I try

> olddomain.com/login.php

it redirects to

> newdomain.com/public_html/login.php

which is not working.. Can any one help to fix it.

(Note: If I try only domain name it redirects to new domain perfectly)

Comment: Is this something that just affects `login.php`? Or does  `olddomain.com/<anything>` redirect to `newdomain.com/public_html/<anything>`? Try redirecting to _any_ other domain, do you still get `public_html` in the target URL? (NB: Test with 302 redirects, since they are not cached - 301 redirects are cached by the browser, so you have to make sure you clear the cache all the time!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussed with service provider, as per their instruction I used following code, which works perfectly (As per their information for Virtual Private Server is special case)

**Thanks to all who take efforts to solve my problem**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteOptions inherit
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain\.tld$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.olddomain\.tld$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.newdomain\.tld\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

Comment: If you want to see the improved version of your directives, you can check my update..

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The only thing of significance is the `RewriteOptions inherit` directive. That is unusual. It means that they are using mod_rewrite in .htaccess further up the filesystem path in order to seemingly "correct" the document root (mod_rewrite directives are not normally inherited). (TBH when you see `RewriteRule` substitutions formatted in such a way it does make you think whether they really know what they are doing.)

Answer (score 3):

Just point your new domain to site Root folder, not the your server root folder.

Answer (score 2):

Then you can use this `RewriteRule` directive:

```
RewriteRule ^public_html/(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

It will only backreference the regex `(.*)` excluding the *"public_html/"*.

---

It's nice to see the complete directives that solved your problem. Anyway, you can improve and optimize them by replacing these 3 lines:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain\.tld$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.olddomain\.tld$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.newdomain\.tld\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

With these 2 lines:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain\.tld$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.tld/$1 [R=301,L]
```

That is the perfect way to write them, in my sight..

Comment: it will cause issue for posted data

Comment: @ChiragNandaniya How?